# Exclude txt wildcard contents from Powershell query

Tags: powershell

I'm having a hard time getting this powershell script to exclude the wildcard contents of a test.txt file.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Test.txt:

admin
exchange
root
```

```
Powershell:

$List = Get-Content C:\Test.txt
Get-QADUser -sizelimit 0 | Select SamAccountName, FirstName, LastName | ? {$_.FirstName -NotLike "*$List*" -AND $_.LastName -NotLike "*$List*" -AND $_.SamAccountName -NotLike "*$List*"}
```

---

**Update:**

Thank you all for the assistance you've provided so far.  I ran a sanity check against the below queries and I'm unable to get the -match and

```
-notmatch
```

to equal the result of a simple query.  Do I have incorrect expectations here or should match/nomatch equal the QAD?

---

When I run **@TheMadTechnician** query with

```
-notmatch
```

then run

```
-match
```

the results don't equal the results without the Test.txt

```
$List = GC C:\test.txt
$Filter = "($(($List|ForEach{[RegEx]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"))"
Get-QADUser -sizelimit 0 | Select SamAccountName, FirstName, LastName | ? {$_.FirstName -notmatch $filter -AND $_.LastName -notmatch $filter -AND $_.SamAccountName -notmatch $filter}
```

then run

```
$List = GC C:\test.txt
$Filter = "($(($List|ForEach{[RegEx]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"))"
Get-QADUser -sizelimit 0 | Select SamAccountName, FirstName, LastName | ? {$_.FirstName -notmatch $filter -AND $_.LastName -notmatch $filter -AND $_.SamAccountName -notmatch $filter}
```

The two combined do not equal the output result of

```
Get-QADUser -sizelimit 0 | Select SamAccountName, FirstName, LastName
```

---

When I run **@mjolinor** query with

```
-notmatch
```

then run

```
-match
```

the results don't equal the results without the Test.txt

```
$List = Get-Content C:\Test.txt
$Match = $list -join '|'
Get-QADUser -sizelimit 0 | 
Select SamAccountName, FirstName, LastName | 
? {($_.FirstName,$_.LastName,$_.SamAccountName -notmatch $Match).count -eq 3}
```

then run

```
$List = Get-Content C:\Test.txt
$Match = $list -join '|'
Get-QADUser -sizelimit 0 | 
Select SamAccountName, FirstName, LastName | 
? {($_.FirstName,$_.LastName,$_.SamAccountName -match $Match).count -eq 3}
```

The two combined do not equal the output result of

```
Get-QADUser -sizelimit 0 | Select SamAccountName, FirstName, LastName
```

Sorry about the crappy formatting SO was giving me a hard time about the code not being formatted correctly.

Comment: Instead of `$_.FirstName -NotLike "*$List*"` could you try `$List -notcontains $_.FirstName`. Like is better for string comparison. You have an array so `-contains` and `-notcontains` might be a better fit.

Comment: @Matt -contains and -notcontains won't do a partial match, which is what it looks like he's trying to do with *$list* where it will match any of the words within any portion of a string. RegEx is his best option that I know of.

Comment: You can not simply change -notmatch to -match. You would have to change the -AND's to -OR's as well.

Comment: The results your seeing comparing -match and -notmatch are expected. Using -notmatch will return all the users where none of the three fields match any of the strings in test.txt.  Switching to -match returns the user where all of those fields match one of the strings in test.txt.  So, it's an all or nothing proposition.  Users that have one or two fields that match fail both tests.

Comment: Thanks for explaining guys.  So what would the best way to get List A and B to equal C?  I need to have a sanity check on this.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong here.  I can do the ANDs with the NOTMATCH and the ORs with the MATCH?

Comment: For my solution, run one test using ? {($_.FirstName,$_.LastName,$_.SamAccountName -notmatch $Match).count -eq 3} as posted, and then another using ? {($_.FirstName,$_.LastName,$_.SamAccountName -notmatch $Match).count -ne 3}

Answer (score 2):

Do a regex match. Get the contents, join them with pipes and wrap them in parenthesis, and you're good to go! Check it out:

```
$List = GC C:\test.txt
$Filter = "($(($List|ForEach{[RegEx]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"))"
Get-QADUser -sizelimit 0 | Select SamAccountName, FirstName, LastName | ? {$_.FirstName -notmatch $filter -AND $_.LastName -notmatch $filter -AND $_.SamAccountName -notmatch $filter}
```

This still matches partial strings, just like your `-like *$list*` was attempting (and failing) to do.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I think this should work:

```
$List = Get-Content C:\Test.txt
$Match = $list -join '|'

Get-QADUser -sizelimit 0 | 
Select SamAccountName, FirstName, LastName | 
? {($_.FirstName,$_.LastName,$_.SamAccountName -notmatch $Match).count -eq 3}
```